# How to use geofield migrate extras

Tags: 7, migrations

I can not understand how to use migrate_extras and for example how to use geofield migrate extra support.

I have create a Migration class that work. In my "source" I have 2 "fields" called latitudine and longitudine. I have follow the instruction that I have found in geofiled.inc:

```
$geo_arguments = array(
  'lat' => array('source_field' => 'latitudine'),
  'lon' => array('source_field' => 'longitudine'),
);
// The geometry type should be passed in as the primary value.
$this->addFieldMapping('field_coordinate', 'Point')->arguments($geo_arguments);
// Since the excerpt is mapped via an argument, add a null mapping so it's
// not flagged as unmapped.
$this->addFieldMapping(NULL, 'latitudine');
$this->addFieldMapping(NULL, 'longitudine');
```

But my "test node" is created (via migrate) without "geofileld" field (field_coordinate). But if I comment the lines above and insert this function:

```
public function prepare($node, stdClass $current_row) {
  $node->field_coordinate = array(LANGUAGE_NONE => array(0 => array(
    'geom' => 'POINT ('.$current_row->longitudine." ".$current_row->latitudine.')',
    'geo_type' => 'point',
    'lat' => $current_row->latitudine,
             'lon' => $current_row->longitudine,
             'left' => $current_row->longitudine,
             'top' => $current_row->latitudine,
             'right' =>$current_row->longitudine,
            'bottom' => $current_row->latitudine,
   )));
}
```

"geofield field" is "created".

Where is my error?

Comment: i dont see any error in either approach ... interesting.

Answer (score 6):

Using arguments is deprecated.

Now you can migrate geofields **without migrate_extras**.

```
$this->addFieldMapping('field_location', 'point');
```

And in your prepare row

```
public function prepareRow($row) {
 $row->point = 'POINT (' . $row->longitude . ' ' . $row->latitude. ')';
}
```

Comment: If you still need migrate_extras and want to use this method, you'll need to disable `MigrateGeoFieldHandler`. Go to `admin/content/migrate/configure` and scroll down to the field handlers section to disable it.

Answer (score 2):

Ok, I have found the solution.

From geofield.inc: "Primary value passed to this field must be the geometry type of the geofield: Point, LineString, Polygon" 
But this need to be passed in a different way:

- in the "prepareRow($row)" I need to set "Point" like a current row field:

  ```
  public function prepareRow($row) {
  [...] 
     $row->geo_type = 'point';
  [...]
  }
  ```
- and in the __construct() function the right line is:

  ```
  $this->addFieldMapping('field_coordinate', 'geo_type')->arguments($arguments);
  ```

Now it works.

M.

Comment: good one tracking that down.

Answer (score 0):

Use of arguments is now deprecated. You will get this error:

> The field mapping arguments() method is now deprecated - please use subfield notation instead.

To migrate geofield (2.0) using **migrate_extras** apply the patch in https://drupal.org/node/1997316.

Code using subfield notation:

```php
$this->addFieldMapping('field_location', 'point');
$this->addFieldMapping('field_location:input_format', 'input_format');
$this->addFieldMapping('field_location:geo_type', 'point');
$this->addFieldMapping('field_location:lat', 'latitudine')
   ->xpath('Latitude');
$this->addFieldMapping('field_location:lon', 'longitudine')
   ->xpath('Longitude');
```

Inside prepareRow():

```php
public function prepareRow($row) {
  ...
  $row->geo_type = 'point';
  $row->input_format = 'lat/lon';
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Got it to work without migrate_extras:

in your prepareRow() use:

```
 $row->point = 'POINT (' . $row->longitude . ' ' . $row->latitude. ')';
```

and in the construct:

```
$this->addFieldMapping('field_location', 'point');
$this->addFieldMapping('field_location:geom', 'point');
$this->addFieldMapping('field_location:geo_type')->defaultValue('point');
```